# How to use foreach on Record<string, Object[]> in TypeScript and Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I want to know, how can I recreate this C# code in TypeScript

```
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> sas = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            sas.Add("11", new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" });
            sas.Add("22", new List<string> { "a2", "b2", "c2" });
            foreach(var e in sas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Key);
                foreach(var s in e.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

I expect that I will get in console this:

```
11
a
b
c

22
a2
b2
c2
```

Update

And the most important, how can I use code like this in Angular and why I get undefined un my ngOnInit method?

My Answer class

```
import { Question } from './question';

export class Answer {
    AnswerId: number;
    Content: string;
    IsCorrect: boolean;
    Mark: number;
    QuestionId: number;
    Question: Question;
}
```

Component code

```
testInfo: Record<string, Answer[]>;

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.id)
            this.dataService.getTestStart(this.id)
                .subscribe((data: Record<string, Answer[]>) =>
                {
                    this.testInfo = data; this.loaded = true;
                    console.log(this.testInfo);

                    for (const key in this.testInfo) {
                        console.log(key);
                        for (const s of this.testInfo[key]) {
                            console.log(s.Content)//here is undefined
                        }
                        console.log()
                    }
                });
    }
```

When I try to output s.Content i get undefined. And when I try to output this on page using Angular I got nothing.

```
            <tr *ngFor="let key of testInfo">
                <td class="row-number-column">{{key}}</td>
                <template *ngFor="let s of testInfo[key]">
                    <td>
                        {{s?.content}}
                    </td>
                </template>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: How to recreate this code from c# into typescript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably the most direct 'translation' to typescript.

```
const sas: Record<string, string[]> = {}
sas["11"] = ["a", "b", "c"]
sas["22"] = ["a2", "b2", "c2"]
for (const key in sas) {
    console.log(key)
    for (const s of sas[key]) {
        console.log(s)
    }
    console.log()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript:

```
  const sas: Record<string, string[]> = {};

  sas['11'] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  sas['22'] = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'];

  for (const key in sas) {
    if (sas.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key)
      for (const key2 in sas[key]) {
        if (sas[key].hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
          console.log(sas[key][key2]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plain object as well, that's what the `JavaScript` will get. Or you can type define (apart from `Record`) as

```
const sas: { [key: string]: string[] } = {};
```

And try the JS equivalent as

```js
const sas = {};
sas['11'] = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
sas['22'] = [ 'a2', 'b2', 'c2' ];

for (const key in sas) {
    if (sas.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    
        console.log(key);
        for (const s of sas[key]) {
            console.log(s);
        }
        console.log('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, and how should I use it like this in Angular?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a setup to test Angular code right now. SO your question is about `Angular` not `TypeScript`? From your code, you might have to check the casing `s?.Content` maybe? Also check the data is coming properly in correct format i.e. `Record<string, Answer>` ?

Comment: My question is about `Angular` and `TypeScript`. My data is coming properly, cause when i output `console.log(this.testInfo);` I get data in `Record<string, Answer>` format. When I try to output `s?.Content` I get undefined too.

Comment: Not being able to run your code, `debug` is the only suggestion I have. You should be able to debug your component code easily.

Comment: @Roomey also use the `.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Comment: When I try to output just `s` I get object, but when I try to get `s.Content` I get undefined, so I don't think that the problem connected to `.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Comment: Do you see property `Content` when you log `s` object? Then it's plain weird! Try to debug.